# New cocoa class in Xcode giving @interface and @implementation in implementation file?

Tags: macos

New to OSX programming. It is my understanding that the .m file should only have an @implementation/@end block and the .h file should only have an @interface/@end block. Not sure why when I create a new cocoa class in Xcode (version 6.1) I get both blocks in my .m file?
I would upload an image but I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a "private interface" that is not contained in the header files (and thus not intended for public consumption but just for your internal use).

The most common case is the so-called "[class extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373110/14955)".